# How to access a JSON file in a private Git repo from node API

Tags: node.js, json, git, sendgrid, secret-key

I have a requirement for a personal project where I am using sendgrid api for the email functionality. Here is my POST request written in node.js to trigger email:

```
sendGrid.setApiKey('<API_KEY>');
    const msg = {
    to: '<EMAIL>',
    from: '<EMAIL>',
    subject: req.body.email,
    text: req.body.message
}
```

Currently, the API_KEY is hardcoded in the code. This turns out to be a security issue. So, I created a private repo in Git to keep my API_KEY in a separate JSON file in the repo. I want to know what are the ways to access the key from the JSON file in the private repo? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your code to look for a LOCAL config.json and read the actual keys off of that, and just .gitignore the local config.json so it's never uploaded.

Comment: Thanks @Kasey Chang, cool, this way worked! I am wondering if we can access private repo at runtime? But I guess that's a stretch.